# about mips assembly language

Tags: assembly, mips

This. asm file contains a function that you will write to convert the string data from the income of a record/entry in the spreadsheet and convert it into an integer. Example, convert the string “1234” into the actual integer 1234 in base 10.

this is my code:

```
income_from_record:
#function to return numerical income from a specific record
#e.g. for record "Microsoft,34\r\n", income to return is 34(for which name is Microsoft)

#arguments: a0 contains pointer to start of numerical income in record 

#function RETURNS income numerical value of the asci income in a0 (34 in our example)
    
# Start your coding from here!

    li a0, 0
    #if no student code entered, a0 just returns 0 always :(
    
# End your  coding  here!
    ret
```

```
add  t0, zero, zero
count:
add  t1, t0, a0     
lb   t1, 0(t1)       
beq  t1, zero  countexit
addi t0, t0, 1       
jal  zero, count      
countexit:
addi a0, t0, 0
```

but there is nothing in the Run I/O so did I miss something?

please help me finish this missing part

Comment: Your code doesn't contain any `syscall` instructions (https://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html), so there's no way for it to create visible results except if you're looking with the debugger.  Are you sure this is MIPS, not RISC-V?  The normal calling convention on MIPS returns in `$v0`, but `a0` is normal for RISC-V.

Comment: That is RISC V code not MIPS. `jal zero,` is RISC V, `ret` is RISC V.

Comment: That code is counting the number of characters but not accumulating the characters as base 10 digits into a number.  In other words, it will get the answer 4, because 4 characters are there in total.